# Summary data even when department is missing for a day

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have data submitted by several departments that I need to summarise to output on a report.

Most days, every department submits data. Some days, a department might miss submitting data.

I need to reflect a zero value entry for that department for the day, rather than skipping it.

I don't know why, but this is striking me as a difficult challenge.

If my data looks like this:

```
Date, Department, Employee
1 May 2016, First, Fred
1 May 2016, First, Wilma
1 May 2016, Second, Betty
1 May 2016, Second, Barney
2 May 2016, Second, Betty
3 May 2016, First, Wilma
3 May 2016, Second, Betty
3 May 2016, Second, Barney
```

If I do a count(*) on this data, the output I am hoping for is:

```
1 May 2016, First, 2
1 May 2016, Second, 2
2 May 2016, First, 0
2 May 2016, Second, 1
3 May 2016, First, 1
3 May 2016, Second, 2
```

It's the 3rd line, "2 May 2016, First, 0", that I can't get my output to include.

My underlying data is more complex than above, but above is a reasonable simplex representation of the problem.

I'm at the point where I'm messing around with cursors trying to 'build' this recordset, so I think that's a clue that I need to ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your main table is:

```
create table mydata
(ReportDate date,
 department varchar2(20),
 Employee varchar2(20));
```

We can use the below query:

```
 with dates (reportDate) as
(select to_date('01-05-2016','dd-mm-yyyy') + rownum -1
     from all_objects
     where rownum <= 
to_date('03-05-2016','dd-mm-yyyy')-to_date('01-05-2016','dd-mm-yyyy')+1 ),
 departments( department) as 
( select 'First' from dual
 union all 
 select 'Second' from dual) ,
AllReports ( reportDate, Department) as 
(select dt.reportDate, 
   dp.department  
 from dates dt
cross join 
 departments dp )
 select  ar.reportDate, ar.department, count(md.employee)  
 from AllReports ar
 left join myData md
 on ar.ReportDate = md.reportDate and
    ar.department = md.department
  group by ar.reportDate, ar.department
  order by 1, 2
```

First we generate dates that we are interested in. In our sample between 01-05-2016 and 03-05-2016. It's in `dates WITH`.

Next we generate list of departments - `Departments WITH`.

We cross join them to generate all possible reports - `AllReports WITH`.

And we use `LEFT JOIN` to your main table to figure out which data exists and which are missing.

Comment: Thanks dcieslak -- in your version above, it looks like I have to hard code the Departments via the 'union all' subquery -- is that correct?

Comment: Query it from your master data. Do not use the Departments WITH but your real table.  I guess you have some DEPARTMENT table that has all possible departments.

Comment: Have a date dimension table and a department table.  CROSS JOIN department to your date table, LEFT/OUTER join your attendance table on date and department.  If you have lots of stats that need to be rolled up by day by department, consider marting the data at regular intervals into a rollup table for reporting.

Comment: You can change dates WITH to:    `with dates (reportDate) as
(select to_date(sysdate,'dd-mm-yyyy') - rownum + 1
     from all_objects
     where rownum <= 7)`. It will show you last 7 days.

Comment: Thanks dcieslak and vanlee1987 -- it was particularly useful to me in an ongoing sense to see the way you used the WITH statement.